# Pythonic way for dealing with nested if/else and while

Tags: python

I have the following Python code with multiple if/else and loops. It is becoming a spaghetti code, which I want to avoid if possible.

Briefly, I want the script to run unattended for a period of time (days/weeks), but the real 'core' of the code should only be executed between 9 am and 5 pm.

Can the code be simplified further?

```
shouldweContinue = True

while shouldweContinue:

    today = dt.datetime.now()
    if somefunction():
        if today.time() >= dt.time(9,0):
            instances = functionX()
            shouldweContinueToday = True
            cTime = dt.datetime.now()
            if cTime <= dt.time(17,0):
                for i in instances:
                    print('something here')
            else:
                shouldweContinueToday = False
        elif today.time() >= dt.time(17,0):
            time.sleep(12 * 60 * 60) # sleep for 12 hours i.e. basically wait for tomorrow
        else:
            time.sleep(60) # sleep for 1 min to avoid non-stop looping
    else:
        raise SystemExit()
```

Comment: Do you just need a cron or celery task that runs functionX?

Comment: You can always **invert** a test, especially when you want to exit early: `if not somefunction(): raise SystemExit()`. This allows you to un-indent the code now indented under `if somefunction():`.

Comment: From the software engineering standpoint, try to use functions instead large nested structures.

Comment: Rather than use a flag variable, use `while True:` and `break`. Setting `shouldweContinueToday = True` again in the loop is otherwise redundant, it is always going to be `True` already by that point.

Comment: Unless `somefunction()` and `functionX()` take a long time, `cTime` is close enough to being equal to `today` so as not to matter. Consider removing it. Since `cTime` is a `datetime.datetime()` instance, you *can't compare it with `dt.time()`*.

Comment: `shouldweContinueToday` is set but isn't used - or is this a typo for `shouldweContinue`?

Comment: Rather than test between `today.time()` and a `dt.time()` object with only the our set to a non-zero value, just test against `today.hour` and an integer. E.g. `if today.hour >= 9:`.

Comment: Don't understand why you would sleep for 12 hours then revert to testing every minute until 9am, when you could easily sleep for the *exact* time to the next 9am (allowing for daylight saving changes!). Similarly for the sleep one minute - just sleep til 9am.

Comment: Don't raise `SystemExit` directly; just call `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the real 'core' of the code should only be executed between 9 am and 5 pm.

Then *test for that and only that*. Put that test into a function that won't return until it is between 9 and 17:

```
def wait_for_working_hours():
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    if 9 <= now.hour < 17:
        return

    # not within working hours, sleep until next 9 o'clock
    next9_day = now.date()
    if now.hour >= 17:
        # between 17:00 and 23:59:59.999999, next 9am is tomorrow
        next9_day += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    delta = dt.datetime.combine(next9_day, dt.time(9)) - now
    time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
```

This function just blocks until it is between 9 am and 5 pm.

Other things to change:

- don't use `while flagvariable: ...`, you can use `break` to end a `while True:` loop.
- I'd use `sys.exit()` instead of `raise SystemExit()`.
- Instead of `if test: # do things`, `else: exit`, put the exiting condition up front, early. So `if not test: exit`, and the `# do things` part no longer needs indenting either.

Together with the `wait_for_working_hours` that looks like this:

```
while True:
    if not some_function():
        sys.exit()

    wait_for_working_hours()

    # do things that need to be done during working hours
    # ...
    if some_condition:
        break

    # then sleep for a minute before doing it again.
    time.sleep(60)
```